# Compiling curl with GSS-API on Linux for Kerberos authentication

Tags: curl, kerberos, gssapi

I am new to curl and kerberos both.

I am trying to compile curl with GSS-API support on RedHat Linux box.

When I run configure,

```
./configure --prefix=${PWD} --with-gssapi
```

I get the following error.

```
error :  one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time. Libs used at link-time: -lgssapi -lz -lrt
```

config.log shows:

```
configure:21032: checking if GSS-API support is requested
configure:21035: result: yes
configure:21050: checking gss.h usability
configure:21050: gcc -c -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -I/usr/include conftest.c >&5
    conftest.c:81:17: error: gss.h: No such file or directory
```

I do see gssapi lib files under /usr/lib64 and also found gssapi under /usr/include/

So I tried with the below flags as well, but with no success.

```
--with-gssapi-libs=/usr/lib64 --with-gssapi-include=/usr/include
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

I am trying to get this setup to eventually use GSS-API option with curl in my C++ code to get authenticated against the Kerberos server. But before that I would like to see some data by using curl command line like

```
curl --negotiate -u username:fakepass http://some/protetcted/url
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrong site, superuser.com or Linux & Unix is the right one. You should post your distro, your MIT Kerberos version installed by your package manager. Try curl from your distro first. It needs to be younger than 7.38.0.

Comment: Asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1658385/curl-with-gss-api-on-alpine-docker